# Implementation of Richardson extrapolation in mesh independence study

Tags: numerical-methods, extrapolation

I am busy with a mesh independence study in computational fluid dynamics, where I am systematically refining my mesh and monitoring a certain parameter of interest with the goal that the value should change less and less as the solution converges.

I have however reached a point where computational resources are hindering me from refining my mesh even though it does not seem like the solution has converged.

Apparently Richardson extrapolation can be used to estimate the converged value of the parameter of interest.

Lets say I have the following variables:

```
mesh_size = [63984,142014,346431]
parameter = [0.00324461,0.00306612,0.00304778]
```

Which is plotted as

[image]

It is quite clear the the curve is leveling off, but isn't quite flat yet.

How would I implement Richardson extrapolation to estimate a value of `parameter` at `mesh_size = infinity` ?

I would appreciate some help in how to implement this numerically.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A couple of suggestions: "the curve is leveling off, but isn't quite flat yet" how can you say that from only 3 datapoints? Needs more points before attempting to fit a reliable asymptotic. Secondly, if it's too expensive to refine the mesh, then maybe look into dynamic mesh methods or allow the nodes to move where it matters, i.e., use particle methods such as SPH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Richardson extrapolation works well if you have a theoretical reason to believe (or know) that the error will go as $h^{-n}$ for some known $n$ as $h \rightarrow 0$.  Then the extrapolation is merely a matter of curve-fitting, and the art is in knowing how to weight the points.  On the one hand, the points for smaller $h$ clearly are less susceptible to high-order effects in $h$.  On the other hand, the honest uncertainty (including the fact that configurations may have a longer correlation in Monte-Carlo time than one would naively think) is likely to be bigger for the points at smaller $h$, since you can afford more statistics at smaller $h$.

In LQCD (Lattice Quantum Chromodynamics) this sort of problem arises in several ways.  In one case, the finite lattice spacing effect is well handled by Richardson-like techniques, because theoretical renormalization group calculations tell you about the small-$h$ behavior.  But even in that case, the best results come from "improved actions" which have errors that fall as a higher power of $h$.

In another case, finite volume effects are known to fall off exponentially, with a scale of the lowest effective mass in the problem.  Here RE is less powerful, because you are doing a 2-parameter fit yet you can't vary that mass indepenently (the raw masses you inject in the Lagrangian get renormalized).  But there is not much of a problem because you can see the leveling prominently.

But in LQCD, the most difficult extrapolation is going to light enough quark masses.  And there, theory provides only broad guidance.  The technique used is to push to one finer grid spacing after you think you know the result to some accuracy, to verify that the error behavior you have surmised is correct.  And that one last point generally takes as much time as all the rest of the computation combined.

So my recommended mantra is:

- See if there is any theoretical reason to expect your error to grow as $h^{-n}$ for some specific $n$.  If so, do some careful uncertainty analysis of the individual points (perhaps by breaking the Monte-Carlo time into several parts and evaluating the quantity of interest for each part separately), and do a least-squares fit to get the asymptote.
- If there is no theoretical reason to expect any specific $h^{-n}$ or other simple behavior such as an exponential approach to the limit, then after computing a few points, 
  try to guess the form of the approach.
- If you can make a decent guess as to the nature of the approach to the limit proceed as in the first case.  Be careful to honestly evaluate your uncertainty, because the result may be quite sensitive to the value on an earlier point.  Probably the easiest way to do an honest job of that is to asses the individual point uncertainties, and then do a quick Monte-Carlo letting each of the points vary as gaussians about their actual values to see how you answer would vary.
- If you can't make a confident guess about the nature of the approach to the limit, probably the best result to quote is the result of the final calculation, with an uncertainty of the difference between the last two points, added in quadrature with your estimated uncertainty in the last point.

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough answer. So basically it is not as straight forward a process as I thought.

However, in the field of computational fluid dynamics, the underlying principle is that as the cell size, in this case 'h' in your convention, approaches zero, the numerical solution approaches the physical solution and the error approaches zero. Might this not be a valid reason to relax the stringent requirements for the use of RE?

Comment: If you know how fast the numerical solution approaches the physical solution as a parameterized function of $h$ (for example, if you know or expect that for small $h$ the error ought to go as $e_0h^3$), then you are golden.  If all you know is that the error approaches zero as $h$ approaches 0, and you can't see an obvious pattern in the early points of data, then you are in that 4-th case:  RE will not help you reduce your error with any degree of rigor if you know nothing about that dependency.  See Numerical Recipes for some good discussion on RE.

Comment: I updated my question to be more specific to my current work. Would you perhaps be able to update your answer to guide me in calculating my level of uncertainty of my final answer? The difference between the last 2 points is easy enough, but Im not sure how to add the level of uncertainty of the final value in quadrature. I suppose the 'estimated uncertainty in the last point' is also not trivial, how would I go about estimating that?